# How to make the Filter function in google sheet more flexible by using Index function?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a range of data from column A to column H. I want to extract the entire row of the data from the data range and paste it to column L-column S by matching these 2 conditions:

- The name in column B match with the name in column J
- The `Round` in column A match with the round in cell `L1`.

To achieve that, I'm using `FILTER` function. It works well if there is no repeated name in the same `Round`. In my screenshot above, there are error in cell `L5`& `L10`because there are two `Peter` in `2nd Round`. May I know how should I modified my `Filter` function so that it can print the data in range `A8:H8` to `J5:S5` and also print the data from `A19:H19` to `L10:S10`?

I'm trying to include `INDEX` into the formula, something like:
`=IFNA(INDEX(FILTER( $A$2:$H$21,$B$2:$B$21=J5,$A$2:$A$21=$L$1),COUNTIF()))`
But it doesn't work in the way that I want. Hope to get some advise. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

### Edited

[image]

The screenshot above is the result of using the formula below:

`=query($A$2:$H$21, "where A = '"&L1&"'", 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try query() instead?

```
=query($A$2:$H$21, "where A = '"&L1&"'", 0)
```

or, get all the rows (all names) with

```
=FILTER($A$2:$H$21, $A$2:$A$21=$L$1)
```

---

### EDIT

If you'd really want to lookup the names entered in column J, you can try this convoluted solution

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(J2:J), iferror(vlookup(J2:J&COUNTIFS(J2:J, J2:J, row(A2:A), "<="&row(A2:A)), query( {B2:B21&COUNTIFS(A2:A21, L1, B2:B21, B2:B21, row(A2:A21), "<="&row(A2:A21)), $A$2:$H$21}, "where Col2 = '"&$L$1&"'", 0), {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 0)),))
```

See tab/sheet 'JPV', cell L2 and check if that works for you?

[image: Example]

Comment: Query function seems like doesn't work. If I use `=query($A$2:$H$21, "where A = '"&L1&"' AND B ='"&J5 &"'", 0)`, there will be 2 rows in the data range fulfill my conditions which are row 8 and row 19. So the output will have 2 rows. Since I will have another Query function on cell `L5`, so there will be an error on cell `L5 `: `Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite the data in L6`

Comment: This is the same problem by using `FILTER` function, need to have a way to filter the output so that it will only have one row of output instead of two rows which will cause the error mentioned above, any idea?

Comment: I didn't include the second condition as the query as posted should return all rows that are in the 2nd round. Maybe duplicate the sheet, remove all formulas you have in col L and then try the formula in L2.

Comment: Yes, it would able to return all the rows that are in the 2nd round, but it doesn't match with the name in column J, sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: Can you maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oO-uolU_BCTWXAB31bggUd8YkiY7GH1kXDfiGjN0juE/edit#gid=0

Comment: I also edited my question to show the output of using `Query` in `L2`

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Do you mind to explain how does the `Countifs` works in the `vlookup` and `query` function? I tried to test the `countifs` function only for understanding purpose but it doesn't work individually without `Arrayformula`

Comment: In the variation tab I isolated the first countif and entered it in K2. As you can see there the formula creates a tally of the names found in J. The same approach is used in the query. Then the name and the number is used in the vlookup to retrieve the correct row. The LEN-part is there to limit the output to those rows that have a value in column J.

Comment: How about `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` in the vlookup?

Comment: An array with the column numbers (from the lookup range) that the vlookup needs to return.

Comment: But why it start from {2,...} instead of {1,..}? Because the lookup range is `A2:H21` so I thought column A should be 1 instead of 2?

Comment: Well, the first element of the query is an inline array { } where the first element (or column) is B2:B21&COUNTIFS(A2:A21, L1, B2:B21, B2:B21, row(A2:A21), "<="&row(A2:A21) and the second element is the actual source range: $A$2:$H$21}. That means the latter starts from column 2 to 9.

Comment: I created an extra tab 'Steps' with the three major steps of the solution. It may help you in understanding how the solution works.

Comment: Thanks JPV, really appreciate your effort to break down the formula, I can understand it already, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a small data set, you can also use the Data > Create a Filter and then choose 2nd Round in column A. When you are done, just Date > Turn off Filter. And you have a quick way to look at the filtered and unfiltered data without the need to scroll right.

Another idea is to create a second sheet. Name the first sheet Data, the second sheet Round 2, third sheet Round 3, etc.

Then add the header row in row 1.

In cell A2 of the Round 2 sheet enter:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:H21,"where A = '"&A1&"'",0)
```

That will provide you with all the round 2 data in a separate sheet.